# Ansible shell command -a with special characters "

Tags: shell, command, ansible, double-quotes

I´m using ansible -a command to execute on my inventory some tastsk (df -h, check folders...). But now, I need to create a user on all the hosts.

I´m using the following command:

```
ansible -i [INVENTORYNAME].inventory allservers -m shell -a "sudo useradd -c "Name & lastname" [USERNAME]" >> [FILE].txt --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=[MYPASS]" -b
```

But it doesn´t work. How can I include special characters in my commands?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current command has nested double quotes.

You can either use single quotes outside:

```
ansible -i inventory all -m shell -a 'sudo useradd -c "Name & lastname" [USERNAME]' >> [FILE].txt --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=[MYPASS]" -b
```

or escape the double quotes inside:

```
ansible -i inventory all -m shell -a "sudo useradd -c \"Name & lastname\" [USERNAME]" >> [FILE].txt --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=[MYPASS]" -b
```

The second options will allow you to include environment variables from the machine executing the Ansible command (your PC).

As a side note, I highly recommend using the [user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_module.html).
`sudo` is also redundant if you use `-b`

Comment: It works some times, but others show:

[HOST] | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: useradd: command not found

Thank you for your advices

Comment: That is unrelated to Ansible. It is probably because you have a mix of different Linux distributions.
On CentOS/Fedora you need to be root to run useradd and the full path is /usr/sbin/useradd - either use the full path to the command or add /usr/sbin to your $PATH.